# Service Fabric Error: Failed to ACL folders or certificates required by application. Error:FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am stumped on this one. I have a secure cluster with some encrypted application settings. The app runs fine on my local cluster, but not when deployed to the cloud.

The application deploys ok, but fails to start up with the following error: Failed to ACL folders or certificates required by application. Error:FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND.

I have created a self signed cert, exported it (with the private key) to a PFX,  and uploaded it to the vault:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type DocumentEncryptionCert -KeyUsage     DataEncipherment -Subject mycert -Provider 'Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0'

Invoke-AddCertToKeyVault -SubscriptionId 'xxxxx-bxxxxfb9-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx' -ResourceGroupName 'vault-sec-studio-dev' -Location "Central US" -VaultName 'vault-sec-studio-dev' -CertificateName 'mycert' -Password "myPass" -UseExistingCertificate -ExistingPfxFilePath "C:\temp\Azure\Dev\mycert.pfx"
```

I add the certificate to the cluster security tab by referencing the thumbprint:
 [image]

[image]

I update the ApplicationManifest.xml:

```
<Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="Service1" AccountType="NetworkService" />
    </Users>
  </Principals>
  <Policies>
    <SecurityAccessPolicies>
      <SecurityAccessPolicy GrantRights="Read" PrincipalRef="Service1" ResourceRef="mycert" ResourceType="Certificate"/>
    </SecurityAccessPolicies>
  </Policies>
  <Certificates>
    <SecretsCertificate X509FindValue="72C57495F3034E072CA6F536EEABE984AA869CBC" X509StoreName="My"   X509FindType="FindByThumbprint" Name="mycert"  />
  </Certificates>
```

The Sevice Fabric Explorer page shows the upgrade was installed but failed to start. Several nodes are in error status:

[image]
When remoting in to the VM's I don't see this cert installed. I see the main cert used to secure the cluster, but not this admin cert.

I have tried to manually install the cert on each VM, but getting the same result.

I have spent a ton of time on this, and can't seem to get anywhere, so I'm hopeful someone can give me some pointers here.

**Update:**
I'm seeing this in the event log on the VM. Talks about the private key which makes me think there is something wrong with the cert, or pfx?

```
Failed to get the Certificate's private key. Thumbprint:72C57495F3034E072CA6F536EEABE984AA869CBC. Error: FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: What is the certs used for? is it a web app? I can see that your deployment succeeded. that means that your deployment-related cert is set up correctly.

Comment: The cert is used to decrypt application settings. The app has two node types: public API (stateless), and a stateful reliable service. The stateless service is hosting a .Net Core web api.

Comment: when u publish with the CLOUD settings to your LOCAL env and deploy. do u get the same error?

Comment: No, it works locally. The only difference at the moment between the two is the instance count.

Comment: When you manually installed the certificates on the VMs did they install into the machines personal store rather than the users?

Comment: Both I think? This is what I used to install them manually:

`$file | Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $pwd –Exportable`  

`$file | Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\CurrentUser\My -Password $pwd –Exportable`

Comment: Does the certificate need to be added to the security tab for the cluster? My understanding was that was for used for authentication into the cluster and is potentially another difference to your local instance if your running it as an unsecure cluster locally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is now finally resolved. I can't say I completely understand this, but this is what I found:

1. Don't create the Service Fabric Cluster using the Portal. You'll need to use the template so you have access to configure the certs.
2. Also no need to mess around with Admin Certs on the security tab that I originally did (see original question). Those don't work for this, or at least not the way I'd expect them to.
3. You must edit the ARM template and add the following certificate information to the "secrets" array on each VM:

[image]

Note section above is added and points to a Certificate URL

"settingCertificateUrlValue": {
  "value": "https://vault-my-site.vault.azure.net:443/secrets/studiosecrets/487a94749ee148979cc97a68abe9fd3a"
},

The cluster is now "green" and the app runs fine.

Comment: To add some explanation behind what you found... There are two steps to using a certificate in Service Fabric: 1) Get the cert on the VM, 2) Reference the cert within Service Fabric.  The steps you did in your original question solved #2, but that doesn't actually get the cert itself onto the VM.  The steps you did in your answer solved #1 by telling Azure VMSS to put those certs on the VMs.  Note that if you add the cert during the initial cluster creation then steps #1 and #2 are taken care of, but when adding a cert later you must do #2 yourself.  We are working to improve this scenario.